# matplotlib.pyplot hangs up at any call

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, matplotlib, freeze

pyplot hangs up at any call, like this one:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
```

or this one:

```
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
```

One core of the CPU keeps running at 100%.

Any other call using pyplot (`plt.*`) will give the same result.

I am using ubuntu 16.04.LTS, python 2.7.12 and matplotlib 1.5.3

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled Ubuntu and it works now. Otherwise nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

try ipython from anaconda. 
What is your PC configuration? 12MHz with 8MB Ram? 
Plotting data with matplotlib is an absolute basic task